# TCPListener blues, can't figure out why the connection doesn't close correctly

Tags: .net, sockets

My TCPListener is configured like this:

```
this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, config.portNum);
```

I then (using threading) setup a listener function like this:

```
private void ListenForClients()
    {
       this.tcpListener.Start(); 

       while (true)
       {
         //blocks until a client has connected to the server
         TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

         //create a thread to handle communication 
         //with connected client

         ThreadStart starter = delegate { HandleClientComm(client, this.DBGrid); };
         Thread thread = new Thread(starter);
         thread.Start();
        }
     }
```

First time around it works, 2nd time I fire this , I get this error message:

*Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally 
permitted*

Inside the thread there is a call to close:

```
tcpClient.Close();
```

But it doesn't seem to free the port up, any suggestions?

Comment: What is the specific line of code that you get the exeception on?

Comment: this.tcpListener.Start();  causes the problem 2nd time round.

Comment: Are you calling tcpListener.Start more than once in the same process or that once you shut your process down and restart it you get the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call to `ListenForClients` repeatedly, that is the source of your problem, not that client connection doesn't `Close()` correctly.

Traditionally, one thread would handle opening main socket and accepting 'child' connection sockets.  So your `ListenForClients` should be in the main server thread, and called only once per application.

SOME MORE INFO:

```
this.tcpListener.Start();
```

creates a listening socked at the port you specified.  With every client connecting,

```
TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

line will create a NEW socket that is connected and is on a totally different port.  So by closing your client, you don't release your main socket at all.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket#Socket_states_and_the_client-server_model

> Computer processes that provide application services are called servers, and create sockets on start up that are in listening state. These sockets are waiting for initiatives from client programs. For a listening TCP socket, the remote address presented by netstat may be denoted 0.0.0.0 and the remote port number 0.
>
> A TCP server may serve several clients concurrently, by creating a child process for each client and establishing a TCP connection between the child process and the client. Unique dedicated sockets are created for each connection. These are in established state, when a socket-to-socket virtual connection or virtual circuit (VC), also known as a TCP session, is established with the remote socket, providing a duplex byte stream.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with tcpListener.Start(). You are not allowed to have 2 listeners on the same port. The ListenForClients method should be called only once in your application